# move image according to displacement field by NumPy

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I have optical flow that computed by some algorithm and i want to get new image from another by my flow

I use following procedure

```
def translateBrute(img, u, v):
    res = np.zeros_like(img)
    for i in xrange(img.shape[0]):
        for j in xrange(img.shape[1]):
            res[i, j] = takePixelInterpolated(img, i + v[i, j], j + u[i, j])
    return res
```

where takePixelInterpolated compute pixel value in point (i + v[i, j], j + u[i, j]) by interpolation

```
def takePixel(img, i, j):
    i = i if i >= 0 else 0
    j = j if j >= 0 else 0
    i = i if i < img.shape[0] else img.shape[0] - 1
    j = j if j < img.shape[1] else img.shape[1] - 1
    return img[i, j]

def takePixelInterpolated (img, x, y):
    i, j = int(x), int(y)
    dx, dy = x - i, y - j
    p1 = takePixel(img, i, j)
    p2 = takePixel(img, i+1, j)
    p3 = takePixel(img, i, j+1)
    p4 = takePixel(img, i+1, j+1)
    return (p1 * (1 - dx) * (1 - dy) +
        p2 * (dx) * (1 - dy) +
        p3 * (1 - dx) * ( dy) +
        p4 * (dx) * ( dy))
```

img is some image (numpy array with shape [height, width, 1 or 3])
u and v is float matrix with shape [height, width] that contains component of displacement field

But this procedure has bad performance. Is there way to do it by NumPy (or opencv or smth) built-in function?

PS Sorry for my poor English

Comment: The bottleneck is almost certainly `takePixelInterpolated`. Looping over each pixel and processing it individually is guaranteed to be slow if the image is reasonably large. It would be much faster if you could modify this function to process multiple pixels simultaneously. Could you show us the code for `takePixelInterpolated`?

Comment: @ali_m I edit post and add takePixelInterpolated definition. I agree with you but i have no idea how make it faster. Except implementing method as C extension

Comment: Are you aware of the `remap` function (see [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#remap)) ?

Comment: @AldurDisciple hmmm, pretty intresting

Comment: @AldurDisciple Thank you, i obtain solution!